# Redirect issue selenium

Tags: python, selenium, redirect, google-compute-engine

I have made a selenium script for a school project that goes to my (or another) public linkedin page and grabs the name. The script works fine on my local computer but when I run it on google cloud compute engine, the page gets redirected to a login page. Why does it redirect on a server but not on my local computer? And how do I prevent it from redirecting?

Hope you can help me.

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.linkedin.com/in/MYNAME")
print driver.current_url
print driver.title
```

Comment: Can you open the browser and enter the URL manually on your Google machine? Is it the same behavior as with Selenium?

Comment: The google virutal machine does not have a screen right? but when I go to the public page I get as url: [link](https://www.linkedin.com/start/join?trk=login_reg_redirect&session_redirect=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.linkedin.com%2Fin%2FMYNAME)

Comment: If the google machine doesn't have a screen, how do you know that you get redirected to a login page?

Comment: That's why I have the print driver.current_url term in. I only have the terminal on the Virtual Machine

Comment: Can you take a screenshot using `driver.TakeScreenshot();` (or whatever it is called in Python)? What's on the page? It it something google server-specific? Maybe credentials for the proxy server or something?

Comment: I'll try but I already visited the url that it went to so I have an idea what it looks like. It is just the standard register/log in page. I need to figure out why it redirects and how I can block it.

Comment: @Mats, did you save the passswords in your browser , like checking `remember me` or any similar such ones?

Comment: Well I dont want to log in, I want to stay on the non log in public page, but it redirects me. Also I have not logged in via the compute engine

Comment: With Selenium, Firefox usually "forgets" across sessions when a user has set the "remember login" checkbox. So this is probably not the reason. But I don't have a clue either. :-(